# getting a data as html string how can i convert it into html.I used dangerouslySetInnerHTML but the html string contains lot of /n and /r

Tags: next.js, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

"description": "

Hello.

\r\n    \r\n      <style>\r\n       .button{\r\n           \r\n           width:100%; \r\n           display:flex;\r\n           border: 1px solid #bf9116; ;\r\n             padding:10px ; \r\n         justify-content:center;\r\n             color:#bf9116;;\r\n          \r\n          box-shadow:0px 1px 5px 1px #bf9116;\r\n    }  \r\n.column{\r\npadding-top:71px;\r\n}\r\n        </style>"

```
        <h2>{data.title}</h2>
```